# Text is cut off in python print statement

Tags: python

I am trying to create a very simple python print statement:

```
user_name = 'bluethundr'
print("Sorry. The user % already has the maximum number of access keys." % user_name)
```

But in the output the word 'already' is cut off, the first letter 'a' doesn't appear in the output when I run the script:

```
Sorry. The user 'bluethundr'lready has the maximum number of access keys.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I print this statement correctly?

Comment: I hadn't realized whitespace after `%` was ignored, but the `a` in "already" is treated as the format character. You want `%s`, not `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3):

> Python’s `str.format()` method of the string class allows you to do
>   variable substitutions and value formatting. This lets you concatenate
>   elements together within a string through positional formatting.

```
user_name = 'bluethundr'
print("Sorry. The user {} already has the maximum number of access keys.".format(user_name))
```

**EDIT**:

Just a bit of explanation for positional arguments:

```
print("DirtyBit is a {3}, {2}, and a {1} {0}!".format("angry one", "very", "shark", "hungry"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
DirtyBit is a hungry, shark, and a very angry one!
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Converts other data types to a string if it can then inserts it into the brackets. Note that the order which your arguments are in the format() is the order they are placed in the string. You can change this default behaviour if you insert the relevant index inside the brackets

Comment: Pardon me, it replaces the brackets with the string or variable in `format()`

Comment: @Swift didn't you mean that in the first place? :p

Comment: It's exactly what I meant in the first place but it could be interpreted that the brackets will stay there after the string is inserted, which of course is not the behaviour we expect from `format()`

Comment: Thanks! I agree. That's the best way to do it. I'll be using this from now on I think.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `%s` for strings, otherwise it will not work correctly.

```
print("Sorry. The user %s already has the maximum number of access keys." % user_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare it as a string. You can read more about input and output in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

```
user_name = 'bluethundr'
print("Sorry. The user %s already has the maximum number of access keys." % user_name)
```